# How to return a value from a range if cell contains that value

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I have a list of Names (First and Surname) in A:A. I also have a range called 'Surnames'. How can I apply a formula so that B:B returns the surname only of A:A if that name is found in the range 'Surnames'.

I other words, I want to check a cell in A1, if part of this cell value contains a name listed in my range of surnames, return the surname that A1 include in B1.

I hope this makes sense, and thank you in advanced :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula in B1 copied down

`=IF(COUNTIF(Surnames,REPLACE(A1,1,FIND(" ",A1),"")),REPLACE(A1,1,FIND(" ",A1),""),"")`

The `REPLACE/FIND` part extracts the surname from A1 (assuming A1 is in the form `<firstname><space><surname>`) and then the formula uses `COUNTIF` to count that surname in your named range. If it's there the surname is returned, otherwise you get a blank.

There may be shorter ways but this should ensure a match with the surname, otherwise you might get "false positives" if part of the surname (or the firstname) might match a surname

Comment: Many Thanks, sorry should have said, the data is jumbled with Numbers also so not laid out as <Firstname><space><Surname> but is random. I actually used this as an example scenario. Another way of putting it is as a list of transactions from companies in A:A, some call themselves "MCDONALDS 736372 AY" whereas other companies may be "WALMART PLC 8736265      937". I have made a list that would include "MCDONALDS" and "WALMART". What I wish to do is put the shortened name in the cell next to it i.e B1. so A1='MCDONALDS 736372 AY' and B1='MCDONALDS'

Comment: Is there any pattern - is the company name always at the start? If not try this version `=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH(Surnames,A1),Surnames),"")` but that could give "false positives" as mentioned above

Comment: It didn't seem to work, I have made a link to the example with the above formula, but it returns "". https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RnCY2iOTdYNuhK7YSaDCexln8DWv8UuoAUB3G032o9c/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: That version works in Excel but perhaps not in googledocs - This version worked in google - =arrayformula(IFERROR(index(Company_Name,match(true,isnumber(SEARCH(Company_Name,A2)),0)),""))